# Symfony2 Bundle working as a service but not working when calling as a route

Tags: symfony, bundle

When i call my bundle as a service, everything working fine.

When i give a route to my bundle's controller, `__contstruct` stops working and the variables coming from `config.yml` file reasoning this.

These are warnings, but i need to get work to set my variables.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   ATL15\GoogleAnalyticsBundle\Controller\GoogleAnalyticsController::__construct(),
>   called in
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/app/cache/dev/jms_diextra/controller_injectors/ATL15GoogleAnalyticsBundleControllerGoogleAnalyticsController.php
>   on line 13 and defined in
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/src/ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle/Controller/GoogleAnalyticsController.php
>   on line 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your controller as a service aswell in your routing like this:

```
hello:
    pattern:      /hello
    defaults:     { _controller: acme.hello.controller:indexAction }
```

See the documentation chapter [How to define Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).